# Google maps API: Search for nearest train station?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to automate the process of finding the closest train station's name to a given address (server side).

To state it another way, I would like to write a function that given any location string X, it returns the station name string Y.

I have experience with google map's API but I have not found a way to do this.

Just the name is enough information, but any amount of information or a list of the closest stations is OK, as long as I can confirm the closest one on the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Places API web service to get nearest train station. For this purpose you can use nearby search functionality. For example, I have coordinate `45.77940539999999,15.9516292` and want to find a nearest train station.

Using [web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=45.77940539999999%2C15.9516292&rankby=distance&type=train_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you will get the nearest train station with name Remetinec as shown in my screenshot

[image]

As your intention is to implement this in server-side NodeJs, you can use the Node.js client library for Google Maps API Web Services

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

The documentation is located at

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/GoogleMapsClient.html

Have a look at the `placesNearby(query, callback)` method.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! So helpful!